# Why NetSuite adds two same buttons to form?

Tags: netsuite

When adding custom button to a form that has form groups, NetSuite adds one button before the form on the page, and then adds a secondary same button at the end of the form. Has anyone come across this problem? Has anyone found a way to fix this or hide secondary button?

Comment: Why is this a problem? All forms have the buttons and actions at both the top and the bottom.

Comment: @Brian its quite small form, and its not visually appealing to have same two buttons, not really a functional problem